# Deleting all nodes of an singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I would like to delete all the nodes present in a singly linked list by passing the headPtr. Here is my code below.

```
void deleteList(node *head) {
    node *curPtr, *temp;
    curPtr = temp = head;

    while ( curPtr != NULL ) {

        temp = curPtr;
        curPtr = curPtr->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    head = curPtr;
}
```

For a list with following nodes ,
1
2
3
4
5
0
I get the following output

0
1213232
123234
2424242
24242424
24242424

Is my code correct  correct ? Is there a better way to do it?

Regards

Comment: Did you test it?  Did it work?  What's your test suite?

Comment: Why implement this yourself when there are standard templates that does this for you?

Comment: Either post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com or ask specific question about your code.

Comment: just to be familiar with the intricacies :)

Comment: Where's your code that creates the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do it. With recursion call,

```
void deleteList(node *head) {
    if(head!=null){
        deleteList(head->next);
        delete head;
    }
}
```

Hope it helped..

Answer (score 1):

It looks good to me except the last line.

```
head = curPtr;
```

has no value whatsoever.